# Prevent viewing webpage in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

I recently created a web portal and it seems like internet explorer doesn't support all the new css properties in the page. The webpage looks good on the new edge, chrome and firefox. Is there any way that i can block the users from vewing my webpage in internet explorer by putting a message (just my concept)

"webpage not supported in internet explorer use chrome ,firefox or edge"

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Using [Feature detection](https://modernizr.com/docs/#what-is-modernizr) is your best bet. Keep in mind users with old browsers aren't used to seeing more modern features so if it's just minor style issues and not major js errors the market share of those browsers is very small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Javascript validation. If Internet Explorer is detected a message will be shown to the user and it will then redirect to your custom error page. Modify the variable 'errURL' to reflect your custom error page URL.

```
var msg = "webpage not supported in internet explorer use chrome ,firefox or edge"; 
var errURL = "https://www.google.com"; 
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; 

if(ua.indexOf('Trident') > -1 || ua.indexOf('MSIE') > -1){
  alert(msg); document.location(errURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refer to the example below may help you to display the message if the browser is Internet Explorer.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Test to detect IE browser
</title>

</head>
<body >
<div id="info"></div><br>
<h2>Test Page...</h2>

<script>
function Detect_IE() {
           var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
         
           var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
           if (msie > 0) {
            
             return "IE " + parseInt( ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
           }
         
           var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
           if (trident > 0) {
            
             var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
             return "IE " + parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
           }

           // other browser
           return "false";
         }
         var result=Detect_IE();
         if (result=="false")
         {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML +="<h2>Welcome to the site...</h2>";
         }
         else
         {
          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += "<h2>Dear user you are using " + result + " <br><br>Webpage not supported in internet explorer use chrome ,firefox or edge</h2>";
         }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you for the aswer. But, when i copy and paste your codethere and open using IE i get the output "Test Page"

Comment: The above-posted code works fine, it can be possible that JS is disabled on your end. In that case, enabled the JS or if shows any prompt to allow scripts at the bottom of the IE browser then allow it. It can help you to run the code.